# Row weights on taxonomy

Tags: 7

On my live site I am unable to see the drag and drop functionality only on taxonomy, whereas it is successfully appearing on menus.Below is my screen shot for taxonomy.

[image]

It should be like this:

[image]

Can any one have idea about this?

Comment: no @krishna Mohan,

Comment: it's not an "answer", but use a different browser. I never bothered to figure out why, but sometimes Safari doesn't do the drag/drop,  but Firefox does.

Comment: but on my local machine it is working

Comment: Try enabling  `Aggregate JavaScript files` option at admin/config/development/performance. Sometimes that resolves this type of issues.

Comment: Ok thanku but not even working on another browser. Actually this problem appears only on live site on every browser. If this is the browser issue then I am unable to see this drag drop functionality on menus, but for menus on live site it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling Aggregate JavaScript files option at `admin/config/development/performance`. 
Sometimes that resolves this type of issues

Here is the screenshot

[image]